# IF Null in Model - ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement

Can I declare "IF" statement or something similar to Models in MVC, e.g. here is my code:

```
namespace SolrWeb.Models
{
    public class SolrVariables
    {
    [SolrField("sequentialid")]
    public long Sequ { get; set; }

    [SolrField("exchangestatus")]
    public int ExtId { get; set; }

    [SolrField("msgtype")]
    public ICollection<string> MsgT { get; set; }
    ...
```

So variable:

```
    [SolrField("msgtype")]
    public ICollection<string> MsgT { get; set; }
    -> this if is NULL return Default "0" else return "String"
```

I forgot to put my next important code:

```
...
@foreach (var row in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@row.Sequ</td>
    <td>@row.ExtId</td>
    <td>@row.MsgT.First()</td>
    Because of ".First" if is Null code brake, this is why I whant to have If
    in my Model, so if it is Null, it won't brake...
```

Thanks all for help

Comment: You could declare a private backing variable - but `MsgT` is not a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private ICollection<string> _msgT;

[SolrField("msgtype")]
public ICollection<string> MsgT 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if(_msgT == null)
        {
            return new ICollection<string>() With {"0"};
        }

        return new ICollection<string>() With {"String"};
    };

    set(ICollection<string> value)
    {
        _msgT = value
    };
 }
```